# In Matlab 2012b, how do I jump to a particular code cell?

Tags: user-interface, matlab

In Matlab 2012b, Mathworks switched from menus and toolbars to the ribbon. One thing which I cannot find so far is the drop-down list of code cells. This is what it used to look in Matlab 2012a:

[image]

Does anyone know where it is now? Unfortunately, Matlab documentation on this topic still covers Matlab 2012a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the "editor" tab on the ribbon, there is a "Go To" dropdown that allows you to navigate sections (cell titles) or subfunctions.

[image]

When you click the "Go To" dropdown, you can select, in the blue title bar, whether you want to navigate sections (which are labeled "Section 1" etc, or with their cell titles), or subfunctions.

[image]

Comment: So it doesn't allow navigating to sections in functions any more?

Comment: @texnic: You can choose to either navigate sections (i.e. cell titles) or subfunctions. I've modified my answer to clear up confusion.

Comment: Jonas, your answer was clear. My additional question was: is it true, that one cannot navigate sections in functions any more? Previously there were two buttons for this. Now just one, and the section titles disappear from the list as soon as I put `function test` at the top of the script.

Comment: @texnic: you have to select "Sections" (it'll say "show sections" on the right). See my edit.

Comment: This is an incredibly intuitive design :( Thanks a lot!